# How to make objects solid on javascript canvas?

Tags: javascript

I have made function for making 2 objects solid (for example a player and a wall).

So I kinda have a problem. This function works perfectly if I go to the wall from right and left only, it changes my position. Same if only from top and bottom. But when I combine all that functions, my hero can't understand where he is and changes my position like I'm coming from top or bottom, but actually i'm coming from left or right. I stuck, what is wrong?

```
    makeSolid(object1, object2)
{
    if(this.collisionDetectedBetween(object1, object2) && object1.x > object2.x - object2.width && object1.x < object2.x)
        object1.x = object2.x - object2.width;
    else if(this.collisionDetectedBetween(object1, object2) && object1.x < object2.x + object2.width && object1.x > object2.x)
        object1.x = object2.x + object2.width;
    else if(this.collisionDetectedBetween(object1, object2) && object1.y < object2.y + object2.height && object1.y > object2.y)
        object1.y = object2.y + object2.height;
    else if(this.collisionDetectedBetween(object1, object2) && object1.y > object2.y - object2.height && object1.y < object2.y)
        object1.y = object2.y - object2.height;
}
```

Comment: It won't work like this. Determine while moving, if you collide stop. Like this: `while(true){ if(!collide(player,wall)) player.x++; }`

Comment: @Jonasw

Oh, it wonk work. My object goes through the other one like there is no collision at all. [That's how function looks right now](https://jsfiddle.net/e9Lo78rc/1/)

Comment: Remove the middle else

Comment: @RomanCortes. Unfortunately, it goes through it anyway. Maybe source can help, [have a look please](https://github.com/danmoop/moople.js---html5-library/blob/master/Examples/Collision/Moople.js#L110)

Comment: Can you try removing all elses?

Comment: @RomanCortes. I ain't sure if I should check if collisionDetectedBetween is false. Because while you are overlapping object this is true. But if you check it when it is false, then it never happens.
[CollisionDetectedBetween function](https://github.com/danmoop/moople.js---html5-library/blob/master/Examples/Collision/Moople.js#L100)
Btw, I removed all elses, nothing has changed.

Comment: Then maybe what you should do is to always remember the previous position of the character. Check collisions, if any happens, then move the character to this previous position. After that, update previous position equal to current position

Comment: Dan, are you sure your function collisionDetectedBetween is right? I'm checking it, but I think I would rewrite it

Comment: Checked, it seems to be right